# File exported to blank excel - PHP

Tags: php, excel

I implemented within my project the possibility of being able to extract in xls format, all the fields selected through the check boxes in the data table initializing before the while loop a form that aimed at an external page where the whole php is enclosed , only that at the time of extraction the excel table comes back empty I put my two pages of codes:

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">


td{
  text-align: center;
}</style>

<?php
//fetch.php
include '../../../connessione.php';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $cerca = mysqli_real_escape_string($connessione, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM ca2_2ac_impianti_in_attivita
  WHERE codice_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR cim_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR indirizzo_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR citta_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR categoria_strada_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR tipo_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR formato_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR caratteristiche_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR quartiere_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR municipio_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR cap_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR categoria_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR longitudine_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR latitudine_impianto_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR nominativo_cliente_in_attivita LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR data_inizio LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
  OR data_fine LIKE '%".$cerca."%'
 ";

}
else
{

 $query = "SELECT * FROM ca2_2ac_impianti_in_attivita ORDER BY id_impianto_in_attivita";

}

$result = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
?>

<div class="px-4">

<div class="table-wrapper">



<form action="excel_specifico.php" method="POST">

<input type="submit" name="invia" value="Excel Specifico" class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
<!--Table-->
<table id="tablePreview" class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm table-borderless">

<!--Table head-->
<thead style="text-align: center;">
<tr>
<th>
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox" class="mr-2 label-table"></label>
</th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Seleziona</strong>  </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Codice</strong>  </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>CIM</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Indirizzo</strong> </th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Città</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Categoria</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Tipo</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Formato</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Caratteristiche</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Quartiere</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Municipio</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Cap</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Categoria</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Longituidine</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Latitudine</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Cliente</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Data Inzio</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Data Fine</strong> </a></th>
<th class="th-lg"><a href=""><strong>Azioni Impianto</strong> </a></th>
</tr>
</thead>
                <!--Table head-->


<?php

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
?>
                <!--Table body-->
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1" class="label-table"></label>
</th>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<div class="form-check">

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id_impianto_in_attivita']; ?>" name="id_impianto_in_attivita[]" class="custom-control-input" id="<?php echo $row['id_impianto_in_attivita']; ?>">
<label class="form-check-label" for="<?php echo $row['id_impianto_in_attivita']; ?>"></label>
</div>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['codice_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['cim_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['indirizzo_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['citta_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['categoria_strada_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['tipo_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['formato_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['caratteristiche_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['quartiere_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['municipio_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['cap_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['categoria_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['longitudine_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['latitudine_impianto_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['nominativo_cliente_in_attivita'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['data_inizio'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
<?php echo $row['data_fine'] ;?>
</td>

<td style="vertical-align: middle;">

<a href="#elimina<?php echo $row['id_impianto_in_attivita']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-rounded"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> ELIMINA</a>
<a href="#"><?php echo "<a href='paginadettaglio.php?id_impianto_in_attivita={$row['id_impianto_in_attivita']}' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-rounded'>Dettagli</a><br>";?></a>
<?php include('modali.php'); ?>

</td>
</tr>

</tbody>

  <?php
}
 }
else
{
 echo 'Nessun risultato corrisponde alla tua ricerca';
}

?>

</table>
<!--Table-->
</form>
</div>

<hr class="my-0">
</div>


<script>
</script>
```

excel_specifico.php:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once('conexao.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contato</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['invia'])){
            // Definimos o nome do arquivo que será exportado
            $arquivo = 'excel_specifico.xls';

            // Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<table border="0">';



            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td><b>ID</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Nome</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>E-mail</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Assunto</b></td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';

            foreach($_POST['invia'] as $id => $invia){
                //echo "ID do item: $id <br>";
                //Selecionar todos os itens da tabela 
                $risultato_query = "SELECT * FROM ca2_2ac_impianti_in_attivita WHERE id_impianto_in_attivita = $id LIMIT 1";
                $risultato_contatto = mysqli_query($conn , $risultato_query);

                while($campi_selezionati = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato_contatto)){
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$campi_selezionati["id_impianto_in_attivita"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$campi_selezionati["codice_impianto_in_attivita"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$campi_selezionati["cim_impianto_in_attivita"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$campi_selezionati["indirizzo_impianto_in_attivita"].'</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
                    $html .= '</tr>';
                    ;
                }
            }
            // Configurações header para forçar o download
            header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
            header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header ("Pragma: no-cache");
            header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
            header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
            // Envia o conteúdo do arquivo
            echo $html;
            exit;
        }else{
            echo "Nenhum item selecionado";
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```